# Scrollbar 'representation'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a scrolling tbody in my html page. For certain reasons (mainly performance reasons) I only show 25 rows in that div instead of the 1.000 or 10.000 rows that exist in the underlying data variable / DB.

Right now I do something much alike to what DataTables.net does; I rotate the contents of those 25 rows on scroll event. Works fine.

One thing that annoys me though is that for instance you have 1000 rows, 25 showing: the scrollbar moves just like always but only takes in to account the 25 rows (because it only sees those, duh ;-) ).

DataTables' solution though show a scrollbar that moves down according to those 1000 rows so it moves a lot slower and dragging it all the way down really goes to record 1000 instead of 25.

Does anyone know how to maybe influence the 'presentation' of the scrollbar in a way that DataTables are able to? (I've googled a lot but no dice)

I use html5, Javascript / jQuery and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the length of the scrolling container depending on the total number of rows, then dynamically load the visible rows into view, when the user stops scrolling.

This means that you need to know the *exact* height of one row, and you'll have to manually position the rows in the container. Sorting the rows might be an interesting problem then.

To make that all a little easier, it might perform well enough if you add only the 1.000 rows, without the data, then dynamically load the data.